# Can't pass doctrine validation test

Tags: php, validation, orm, doctrine

I have 5 entities and 5 mappings, I've done most of the orm mapping and ik mostly works, but I can't seem to pass the validation test: `php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate`

These are my mappings:

file: Organisation.orm.yml

```
AppBundle\Entity\Organisation:
type: entity
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }
fields:
    # irrelevant fiels
    # ...
oneToOne:
    creator:
        targetEntity: Person
        inversedBy: organisation
        joinColumn:
            name: creator_id
            referencedColumnName: id
oneToMany:
    vacancies:
        targetEntity: Vacancy
        mappedBy: id
```

file: Person.orm.yml

```
AppBundle\Entity\Person:
type: entity
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }
fields:
    # irrelevant fiels
    # ...
oneToOne:
    organisation:
        targetEntity: Organisation
        mappedBy: creator
oneToMany:
    testimonials:
        targetEntity: Testimonial
        mappedBy: receiver_id
manyToMany:
    skills:
        targetEntity: Skill
        mappedBy: null
        joinTable:
            name: person_has_skill
            joinColumns:
                -
                    name: person_id
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                -
                    name: skill_id
                    referencedColumnName: id
```

file: Skill.orm.yml

```
AppBundle\Entity\Skill:
type: entity
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }
fields:
    name:
        type: string
        length: 100
manyToOne:
    parent:
        nullable: true
        targetEntity: Skill
        joinColumn:
            name: parent_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

file: Testimonial.orm.yml

```
AppBundle\Entity\Testimonial:
type: entity
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }
fields:
    value:
        type: text
    approved:
        type: boolean
        nullable: true
manyToOne:
    sender:
        targetEntity: Person
        joinColumn:
            name: sender_id
            referencedColumnName: id
    receiver:
        targetEntity: Person
        joinColumn:
            name: receiver_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

file: Vacancy.orm.yml

```
AppBundle\Entity\Vacancy:
type: entity
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }
fields:
    title:
        type: string
        length: 100
    description:
        type: text
    startdate:
        type: datetime
    enddate:
        type: datetime
manyToOne:
    organisation:
        targetEntity: Organisation
        inversedBy: vacancies
        joinColumn:
            name: organisation_id
            referencedColumnName: id
manyToMany:
    skills:
        targetEntity: Skill
        nullable: true
        mappedBy: null
        joinTable:
            name: vacancy_has_skill
            joinColumns:
                -
                    name: vacancy_id
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                -
                    name: skill_id
                    referencedColumnName: id
```

And this is my validation error:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/AqhRxxQ.jpg]
I've been at it for days now and I can't seems to find the solution. Would love to hear from someone who knows more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here, found the answer...

in Organisation.orm.yml I had to set:

```
OnetoMany:
    vacancies:
        targetEntity: Vacancy
        mappedBy: organisation
```